# how does one deploy a python script with a mysql database to another computer

Tags: python, deployment, mamp

I have a simple python script and mysql database for my elderly friend to manage his medications I developed with MAMP and python on my Mac.  How do I deploy it to his Mac, simply, without having to reinstall MAMP on his MAC and creating the tables, etc. ?

Comment: I don't know why it has one vote down and no comment as to why.  That isn't helpful at all whoever voted this down.  Please advise what the issue is so it can be addressed and also my question can be answered so I can help my elderly friend.  Lets help each other help others.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems to be common practice at SO to downvote questions or answers without adding a comment that explains. Helping newcomers doesn't seem to be that important.
The excuse is mostly to have to clean SO as fast as possible and having no time for better explaining

This doesn't make it easy for more recent members to improve.

That said.

Your question isn't really a programming question.It's perhaps better suited for https://superuser.com/users/1092490/

Comment: Do you really need mysql? Couldn't you just use sqlite? (convert the database to sqlite?)
It would make things easier and simpler and you could just use pyinstaller to create a standalone directory, that you could archive and give your friend?

Comment: If you want to stick with Mysql I wouldn't bother to find a magic bullet. Just work a little more manually and help your friend

Just install MAMP and give him your code.
To copy the database. just dump it on your machine copy the dump file, create a db and 'execute' the dump.

Comment: pyinstaller could be used to package your code and perhaps the database dump

and any other means to install MySQL could do the rest. I'm no MAc user so I can't help there.

Comment: KlausF thanks for your insight... I have switched to sqlite3 file DB and it is much less than installing mysql, etc.  Thanks for the direction.  This is what I thought SO was all about when I joined it years go.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

KlausF thanks for your insight... I have switched to sqlite3 file DB and it is much less than installing mysql, etc. Thanks for the direction. This is what I thought SO was all about when I joined it years go. Thanks again